# AGGrid: scrolling to specific position in pixels, not row index

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I need to scroll AgGrid precisely to certain position in pixels. That's because I show it alongside with a chart drawn in d3 and want those two to scroll synchronously.

`ensureIndexVisible` doesn't fit my needs and I didn't find any similar documented feature. The best idea I came across is manually setting `scrollTop` to div with class `ag-body-viewport` which is a terrible hack.

Any better ideas?